# Как правильно сократить слово "через"?

Tags: сокращения

Возник спор, как правильно сократить слово ЧЕРЕЗ ?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Незачем.
Вариант насчет междугородних автобусов (впрочем, не только) я никак не могу признать нормативным.